# Determine if a value pulled from a file falls within a range

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml, range, standard-deviation

So I have to write a code that determines whether a value pulled from a file falls within a specific range.

```
                double averageMaximumX = query.Average(t => double.Parse(t.XMax));
   double varianceMaximumX = query.Sum(t => Math.Pow(double.Parse(t.XMax) - averageMaximumX, 2));
                varianceMaximumX /= query.Count();
                double stdDevMaximumX = Math.Sqrt(varianceMaximumX);

                double averageMinimumX = query.Average(t => double.Parse(t.XMin));
   double varianceMinimumX = query.Sum(t => Math.Pow(double.Parse(t.XMin) - averageMinimumX, 2));
                varianceMinimumX /= query.Count();
                double stdDevMinimumX = Math.Sqrt(varianceMinimumX);

                double averageMaximumY = query.Average(t => double.Parse(t.YMax));
   double varianceMaximumY = query.Sum(t => Math.Pow(double.Parse(t.YMax) - averageMaximumY, 2));
                varianceMaximumY /= query.Count();
                double stdDevMaximumY = Math.Sqrt(varianceMaximumY);

                double averageMinimumY = query.Average(t => double.Parse(t.YMin));
   double varianceMinimumY = query.Sum(t => Math.Pow(double.Parse(t.YMin) - averageMinimumY, 2));
                varianceMinimumY /= query.Count();
                double stdDevMinimumY = Math.Sqrt(varianceMinimumY);

                double averageMaximumZ = query.Average(t => double.Parse(t.ZMax));
   double varianceMaximumZ = query.Sum(t => Math.Pow(double.Parse(t.ZMax) - averageMaximumZ, 2));
                varianceMaximumZ /= query.Count();
                double stdDevMaximumZ = Math.Sqrt(varianceMaximumZ);

                double averageMinimumZ = query.Average(t => double.Parse(t.ZMin));
   double varianceMinimumZ = query.Sum(t => Math.Pow(double.Parse(t.ZMin) - averageMinimumZ, 2));
                varianceMinimumZ /= query.Count();
                double stdDevMinimumZ = Math.Sqrt(varianceMinimumZ);


                var results = from item in query
                              select new
                              {
       XMaxResult = TryParseWithDefault(item.XMax, double.NaN) <= averageMaxX ? "pass" : "FAIL",
       XMinResult = TryParseWithDefault(item.XMin, double.NaN) >= averageMinX ? "pass" : "FAIL",
       YMaxResult = TryParseWithDefault(item.YMax, double.NaN) <= averageMaxY ? "pass" : "FAIL",
     YMinResult = TryParseWithDefault(item.YMin, double.NaN) >= averageMinY ? "pass" : "FAIL",
       ZMaxResult = TryParseWithDefault(item.ZMax, double.NaN) <= averageMaxZ ? "pass" : "FAIL",
        ZMinResult = TryParseWithDefault(item.ZMin, double.NaN) >= averageMinZ ? "pass" : "FAIL"

                              };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add and subtract the standard deviation to the average.

Example

```
XMaxResult = (TryParseWithDefault(item.XMax, double.NaN) <= averageMaxX + stdDevMaximumX 
             && TryParseWithDefault(item.XMax, double.NaN) >= averageMaxX - stdDevMaximumX)  
             ? "pass" : "FAIL"
```

Comment: Let me try it for each condition and see it seems to be good though.